# String data, right truncation error

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I'm calling a stored procedure that inserts html data into a varchar(max) field via ASP, the original html is about 56kb in size. The parameter for the proc is also varchar(max). All the research I've done references buffer size. Any ideas on how to work around this? I use a hosting service so SQL configuration changes could be tricky.

The error I'm getting is "String data, right truncation". Here is the asp code calling the stored procedure.

```
Dim addRS, addCMD
Set addCMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
addCMD.ActiveConnection = objconn
addCMD.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
addCMD.CommandText = "insert_emailjob"

addCMD.Parameters.Append(addCMD.CreateParameter("emailbody",adVarchar,adParamInput,10000000,emailbody))
set addRS = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
addRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
addRS.open addCMD
```

Comment: Buffer size?  The data type supports up to 2 GB, this doesn't appear to be a SQL Server/database question...

Comment: You haven't actually mentioned any specific problem or detailed error message, so what exactly are asking how to work around?

Comment: Show the code calling the SP especially the parameters being added to the command.

Comment: The error is "String Data, Right Truncation". Here is the asp code that calls the sp.

Comment: If you are positive that the SP's corresponding parameter is `varchar(max)`, then I agree with @OMG Ponies, the issue is likely not related to SQL Server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try creating the parameter like this instead:

```
addCMD.Parameters.Append(addCMD.CreateParameter("emailbody", adLongVarchar, adParamInput, Len(emailbody), emailbody))
```

Comment: `adLongVarchar` was the fix for me - previously using `adVarchar`